# Ошибка при использовании LocationManager

Tags: android, android-location

При попытке зарегистрировать слушателя в службе позиционирования:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                1000,
                1,
                listener);
```

Возникает ошибка:

> Call requires permission which may be rejected by user: code should explicitly check to see if permission is available (with `checkPermission`) or explicitly handle a potential `SecurityException`

Хотя в AndroidManifest у меня есть разрешение на получение местоположения:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>`

Почему Android говорит, что пользователь может выключить разрешение, если оно прописано в AndroidManifest'e и как убрать ошибку (вариант, предложенный Android Studio с if проверкой в 260 символов мне не по душе)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это нововведение API 23 - теперь разрешения которые указаны в манифесте не принимаются автоматически, как было раньше, а пользователь может в любое время включить/отключить их.

Потому при выполнении критичного кода, который зависит от разрешения, необходимо каждый раз проверять даны ли разрешения. И в зависимости от этого выполнять или нет функционал.

Чтобы обойти, как вариант, можно установить в Gradle:

```
targetSdkVersion 22
```

должно скомпилиться, но при запуске на железке с АПИ 23 упадет если пермишны не даны.

В приложении, которое будет публиковаться так, конечно лучше не делать,  лучше в любом случае обработать в простейшем случае так: если нет прав, то выход из метода и невыполнение критичной функциональности

```
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
```

Можно выдавать диалог запроса пермишна

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_REQUEST);
```

а затем обработать результат в onRequestPermissionsResult

Лично я делаю так, может тоже понравится:

Интерфейс коллбэка:

```
public interface IPermissionCallback {
    void permissionGranted(PermissionChecker.RuntimePermissions permission);

    void permissionDenied(PermissionChecker.RuntimePermissions permission);
}
```

Класс проверки пермишна

```
public class PermissionChecker {

    public enum RuntimePermissions {
        PERMISSION_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION {
            @Override
            public String toStringValue() {
                return android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
            }

            @Override
            public String showInformationMessage() {
                return MyApplication.getAppContext().getString(R.string.info_message_about_request_permission_fine_location);
            }
        };
        public final int VALUE;

        RuntimePermissions() {
            VALUE = this.ordinal();
        }

        public abstract String toStringValue();

        public abstract String showInformationMessage();
    }

    public boolean isPermissionGranted(Context context, final RuntimePermissions permission) {
        return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission.toStringValue()) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    public void checkForPermissions(Activity activity, final RuntimePermissions permission, final IPermissionCallback callback) {
        if (!isPermissionGranted(MyApplication.getAppContext(), permission)) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, permission.toStringValue())) {
                // Здесь показываем обоснование, почему необходимо разрешение, а делаю через Toast 
                Toast toast = AppUtils.showInfoMessage(activity, permission.showInformationMessage());
                toast.getView().setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MyApplication.getAppContext(), R.color.background_toast));
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
                callback.permissionDenied(permission);
            } else {
                // Запрос диалога пермишна
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{permission.toStringValue()}, permission.ordinal());
            }
        } else {
            // Права даны или АПИ < 23
            callback.permissionGranted(permission);
        }
    }
}
```

В активити реализую интерфейс

```
@Override
public void permissionGranted(PermissionChecker.RuntimePermissions permission) {
    // Разрешение есть
}

@Override
public void permissionDenied(PermissionChecker.RuntimePermissions permission) {
    // Разрешения нет
}
```

обработка результата диалога запроса прав

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION.VALUE) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            permissionGranted(PERMISSION_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION);
        } else {
            permissionDenied(PERMISSION_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION);
        }
    }
}
```

и в onCreate() или onStart() проверяю разрешения

```
private void checkPermissions() {
    PermissionChecker permissionChecker = new PermissionChecker();
    permissionChecker.checkForPermissions(this, PERMISSION_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION, this);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Если Вы тестируете свое приложение на `Android 6.0+`, то такие серьезные `permission` уже нужно обрабатывать, давая пользователю выбор в виде диалога. Диалог создается автоматически по всем правилам, просто вставьте код который указан ниже.

```
 private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST = 1;  

 if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_REQUEST);
    }else{
                 //startActivity(); или вызов метода 
    }
```

P.s. Решения короче еще пока не видел, честно.

Comment: Странное нововведение... Если я использую разрешение в приложении, значит оно нужно! А если пользователь не хочет этим пользоваться — пусть не устанавливает приложение. Не понимаю я Google, а данной ситуации...

Comment: В 6 андроид (и кстати в пятом тоже) пользователь может забирать у приложения определенные права и давать их по запросу, а приложение должно на это адекватно реагировать (или ругаться и завершать работу). Google сделала шаг навстречу здоровой паранойе пользователей, что меня как пользователя радует.

Answer (score 0):

Google сделала шаг навстречу к дибилизму. Метод public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {} вызывается как минимум 1 раз в секунду и каждый раз приходится выполнять этот не кому не нужный код по проверке разрешений