# Добавление кнопки currentLocation

Tags: java, android, google-maps

В google maps хочу реализовать кнопку myCurrentLocation.
В методе onCreate добавил следующее:

```
googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

А также в `AndroidManifest`'e указал нужные `permission`'s:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Но по-прежнему подчеркивает `googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);` со следующей ошибкой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В `API 23` были введены т.н. *runtime permissions* и теперь для получения некоторых разрешений недостаточно записи в `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Все *permissions* делятся на два типа: *normal* и *dangerous*.

Для получения *permissions* из группы *normal* достаточно соответствующей записи в `AndroidManifest.xml`.

**Для получения *permissions* из группы *dangerous*** кроме соответствующей записи в файле `AndroidManifest.xml` **нужно еще в рантайме запросить это разрешение у пользователя**.

`ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` и `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` относятся к категории *dangerous*, следовательно, для получения этих разрешение необходимо дополнительно спросить об этом пользователя.

По поводу того, как запросить разрешения, дан подробный ответ [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/514419/220996) и в [официальной документации](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

Comment: Спасибо, но реализация значительно отличается от того что я уже написал, и того что предстоит написать.